# How to pass two parameters to a 3rd-party component callback property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, single-page-application

I need to use inline edit to update the information, in addition to the updated text, I need to transfer another record id, but I don’t know how to implement it.

```
{this.state.quotes.map((i, val ) => { 
  return(<div onClick={this.handleSubmitPlus.bind(this, i.id)} id={i.id} key={val} style={this.style.allStyle}>
  <EditableLabel text={i.texting}
    labelClassName='weightespenis'
    inputClassName='weightespenis'
    inputWidth='200px'
    inputHeight='25px'
    inputMaxLength={50}
    labelFontWeight='bold'
    inputFontWeight='bold'
    onFocus={this._handleFocus}
    onFocusOut={this._handleFocusOut}
  />
{i.all} / id:{i.id}</div>)})}
```

---

```
_handleFocusOut(text) {
  console.log('Left editor with text: ' + text);
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/cliceds/" + 1, {
   method: 'put',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({texting: text})
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)) 
}
```

I thought to do like this `onFocusOut={this._handleFocusOut(i.id)}` and  `fetch("http://localhost:3001/cliceds/" + ID`  but it is not transmitted, tell me how to implement it.

---

Beginner in programming do not judge strictly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `onFocusOut` property needs to be a function that receives a single `text` argument.

When you do something like `onFocusOut={this._handleFocusOut(i.id)}`, you directly call the `_handleFocusOut` method, instead of passing it as a callback.

What you could do is to provide an anonymous function for the `onFocusOut` callback:

```
<EditableLabel
    ...
    onFocusOut={(text) => this._handleFocusOut(i.id, text)}
/>
```

Of course, you will need to adapt your `_handleFocusOut` method accordingly.